# insert into error - data won't insert

Tags: mysql, insert, sql-insert

```html
  $fnavn = $_POST['fnavn'];
  $enavn = $_POST['enavn'];
  $adresse = $_POST['adresse'];
  $adressenr = $_POST['adressenummer'];
  $postnr = $_POST['postnummer'];
  $kontonr = $_POST['kontonummer'];
  $cvc = $_POST['cvc'];
  $fid = $_POST['frakt'];
  $gid = $_SESSION['gid'];
  $aid = $_SESSION['aid'];
  $sql = "INSERT INTO `bestillinger` (`bestilling_id`, `adresse`, `adressenummer`, `postnummer`, `fornavn`, `etternavn`, `kontonummer`, `cvc`, `time`, `fid`, `gid`, `aid`) 
              VALUES (NULL, '$adresse', '$adressenr', '$postnr', '$fnavn', '$enavn', '$kontonr', '$cvc', now(), '$fid', '$gid', '$aid')";
```

this is my code, for some reason no data is inserted into my database - and i just cant figure out why.

both sessions have a valid value.
After a form is filled out, my database is supposed to put the info into the database. what is the error?

Comment: You should use `mysql_error();` to get the last error. You should also provide a full testable code sample.

Answer (score 1):

You are escaping single quotes inside a double quoted string, so that will actually print the \ character as part of the SQL, rendering your SQL invalid.

You need to replace the \' with just ', or wrap the whole query using ' instead of "

Comment: Actually do we really need to escape the single quotes? As far as i know it works without that.

Comment: @KhaldounNd that was my point, but I guess wasn't so clear in my answer, so elaborated, thanks.

Comment: yes i misread it at first, so you did a good job by elaborating

Comment: so i removed the \' with just '. (edited post), but the information still doesnt show up

Comment: Then you need to provide a fuller working code example and the error that you're receiving? where are your `mysql_query` function calls, or your mysql_connect etc?

Comment: You should provide an answer with details of the error or solution.